# Why does this piece of Scala code not compile?

Tags: scala

The error it yields is:

```
Funct.scala:5: 'val' expected but identifier found.
[error] class Funct[In,Out](function: In => Out, description: String, implicit m: Manifest[In => Out]) {
```

and the code in question is:

```
import scala.reflect.Manifest;

class Funct[In,Out](function: In => Out, description: String, implicit m: Manifest[In => Out]) {

  def isType[K](implicit man: Manifest[K]) = {
    m &lt;:&lt; man
  }

  def Apply(input: In): Out = {
    function.Apply(input)
  }

  def toString() = {
    description + m
  }
}
```

I simply do not see what the problem is.

Comment: You left out the line from the error output with the carrot `^` showing where the parse error happened in the input line. (It's pointing at the `m` just after `implicit`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems you should be able to figure out, but the message is indeed a bit confusing.

The issue here is that the `implicit` keyword must mark the whole parameter group and not just individual parameters.  Try:

```
class Funct[In,Out](function: In => Out, description: String)(implicit m: Manifest[In => Out])
```

Answer (score 3):

`function.Apply(input)` should be `function.apply(input)` or just `function(input)`, but seriously, just use IntelliJ or Eclipse and they'll tell you these things immediately.